# Автоматически добавить блок перед <h2>

Tags: php

Необходимо вставить блок в тексте перед вторым по счету `<h2>`. Есть код:

```
        <?php 

            function addContent($addTo, $add, $cntRep, $after = '<h2>', $openTag = '<div style=" ">', $closeTag = '</div>'){
                $posAfter = 0;
                $cntRep=2;
                for ($i=0; $i < $cntRep; $i++) {
                    $pos = stripos($addTo, $after, $posAfter);
                    $posAfter = $pos+strlen($after);
                    if($pos===FALSE){
                        return $addTo;
                    }
                }
                $beforeAdding = substr($addTo, 0, $posAfter);
                $afterAdding = substr($addTo, $posAfter);
                $result = $beforeAdding . $openTag . $add . $closeTag . $afterAdding;
                return $result;
            }


            $this->item->fulltext = addContent($this->item->fulltext,'
                            <!-- блок который нужно вставить -->
             ',2);

        echo $this->item->fulltext; ?>
```

В результате вставка блока происходит внутри `<h2> </h2>`. Как вставить блок перед `<h2>`, а не после него?